# How can I search for fullname and the rest of info about a person from a file?

Tags: visual-c++

(=
I'm trying to build a simple menu program that adds data, searches for data, and deletes data depending on what the user wants to do.
I have used Struct here as someone here told me, and also someone else told me to use a vector to make it easier for myself. I did both ways but however, I don't know why it is not working at all!
It prints the first person's full name in the file but how can I make it so the code prints all the info as I write the person's full name to the console.

This is my code for the searching function.

```
while (std::getline(in_out_file, lines))
{
  my_vec.push_back(lines); 

      
}
    

   for(int i = 0;i < my_vec.size(); ++i){
       if(search == my_vec[i]){
        std::cout << search << std::endl;
         std::cout << "Match found" << std::endl;
         break;
        //           std::cout << "\n\tThe fullname is     :    " << info.full_name; 
        //  std::cout << "\n\tThe address  is     :    " << info.address; 
        //  std::cout << "\n\tThe E-post is       :    " << info.e_post; 
        //  std::cout << "\n\tThe number is       :    " << info.phone_num; 
        //  std::cout << "\n\tThe birthday is     :    " << info.birth_date; 
        //  std::cout << "\n\tAnything else       :    " << info.anything_else; 
       } else {
         std::cout << "Match not found "<< std::endl;
         break;
       }
   } 
in_out_file.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the `break;` in the else clause otherwise you for loop stops at the first iteration

Comment: Hey Jean!  If I remove it It will Print Match not found repeatedly around 20 times.

Comment: sorry! break; I ment

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/fvmx_bpHt              This is another version of my code. The same problem! Honestly, I have been struggling with it since this morning! (=

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do once you have found a match.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. You probably want to load the file in a vector of records and then search on different keys. Note that `"Tom Cruise"`, `"Cruise Tom"`, `"   Tom            Cruise"` are the same.

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle  I have solved it, However, How can I tell it to continue until all lines are printed?

Comment: Right now it prints only the fullname!

Comment: rest of info?does that mean you want to uncomment these lines: ```//           std::cout << "\n\tThe fullname is     :    " << info.full_name; 
        //  std::cout << "\n\tThe address  is     :    " << info.address; 
        //  std::cout << "\n\tThe E-post is       :    " << info.e_post; 
        //  std::cout << "\n\tThe number is       :    " << info.phone_num; 
        //  std::cout << "\n\tThe birthday is     :    " << info.birth_date; 
        //  std::cout << "\n\tAnything else       :    " << info.anything_else; ```

Comment: Hey Kenash! Thank you for reaching out! Yes, if there is a way to do that please!

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is a working example. The robustness of your program depends on how you check the content of the lines vs the user search pattern.
Here I removed all space in search pattern an line for the matching.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
std::string embedded_test_file = R"(Tom Cruise 
Los Angelse Manchester Street 234 1223
tom@gmail.com
0354221112
23 July
Mission Accomplished

Jordan Jordansson
Georga computerStreet 12 34567
jordan@gmail.com
032456789
20 January
My new book is coming soon)";

struct searching_contact
{

    std::string full_name{""};
    std::string address{""};
    std::string e_post{""};
    std::string phone_num{""};
    std::string birth_date{""};
    std::string anything_else{""};
    std::string new_line{""};
};

string remove_white_space(const string &var)
{
    string res;
    for (const auto &c:var)
    {
        if (c != ' ') {res.push_back(c);}
    }
    return res;
}


int search_contact()
{
    searching_contact info;
    std::stringstream in_out_file{embedded_test_file};

    std::string search{};
    
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    bool found = false;
    std::cout << "Enter Key to search: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, search);
    
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in_out_file, line))
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    auto search_no_space = remove_white_space(search);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "searching: "<< search <<" in <" <<lines[i] <<">" << endl;
        auto line_no_space = remove_white_space(lines[i]);
        if (search_no_space.compare(line_no_space) == 0)
        {
            
            std::cout << "Match found" << std::endl;
            info.full_name = lines[i];
            i++;
            info.address = lines[i];
            i++;
            info.e_post = lines[i];
            i++;
            info.phone_num = lines[i];
            i++;
            info.birth_date = lines[i];
            i++;
            info.anything_else = lines[i];
            i++;
            info.new_line = lines[i];
            i++;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return found == true ? 0 : -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    return search_contact();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it Jean-Marc (=

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/vcXpCt5-T   The link shows the changes I made!

Comment: Still not working, Trying to make it work , Wish me luck  (=

Comment: Do you think This helps

Comment: auto itr = find(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), search );